# Nginx + Docker - "no live upstreams while connecting to upstream" with upstream but works fine with proxy_pass

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

So I've been facing a weird problem, and I'm not sure where the fault is. I'm running a container using docker-compose, and the following nginx configuration works great:

```
server {
  location / {
        proxy_pass http://container_name1:1337;
  }
}
```

Where container_name was the name of the service I gave in docker-compose.yml file. It resolves to the IP perfectly and it works. However, the moment I change the above file to this:

```
upstream backend {
    least_conn;
    server container_name1:1337;
    server container_name2:1337;
}

server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
```

It stops working completely and in error logs I get the following:

```
2020/03/17 13:16:03 [error] 8#8: *11 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: xxxxxx, server: codedamn.com, request: "GET /HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://backend/", host: "xxxxx"
```

Why is that? Is nginx not able to resolve DNS when inside upstream blocks? Could anyone help with this problem?

**NOTE: This happens only on production (Ubuntu 16.04), on local (macOS Catalina), the same configuration works fine. I'm totally confused after discovering this.**

**Update 1:** The following works:

```
upstream backend {
    least_conn;
    server container_name1:1337;
}
```

But not with more than one server. Why?!

Answer (score 0):

Alright. Figured it out. This is because `docker-compose` creates contianers randomly and nginx quickly marks the containers as `down` (I was deploying this on production when there was some traffic). The app containers weren't ready, but nginx was, so it marked them down and stopped forwarding any traffic.

For now, instead of syncing up `docker-compose` container creation order (which was a bit hacky, as I discovered), I disabled the failed attempts of nginx to automatically mark service as down by writing:

```
server app_inst1:1337 max_fails=0;
```

which lets nginx still forward the traffic to a particular service (and my docker is configured to restart the container in case it crashes), which is fine.